# How to deploy a RESTful Jersey webservice through eclipse on Tomcat that is bound to a particular IP Address

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jersey, web-deployment

I have a Tomcat instance that is bound to the the IP address of my machine (10.100.10.63) as shown below:-

```
     <Connector address="10.100.10.63" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"  protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

I have a RESTful web service developed using Jersey. The web service was created as a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse and uses a Tomcat 6.0 as the target runtime server.

When I right click on the web service project in Eclipse and select Run As->Run on Server, the server fails to start.

However, when I remove the address binding from server.xml as shown below, the server starts successfully and I am able to use the web service using localhost.

```
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"  protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

How can I deploy the webservice in such a way that I can bind Tomcat to the IP Address of my machine so that it is accessible from other machines in my network as well.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting on tomcat?

Comment: @EugenioCuevas There are no errors or exceptions in the Eclipse console when Tomcat starts up. After 45 seconds, I get a dialog in eclipse with the error messsage 'Starting tomcat v6.0 at localhost' has encountered a problem. I am not sure why its saying localhost but I guess its the name that I gave the server when I created the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the engine defaultHost property instead of the address in the connector, in server.xml:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="10.100.10.63">
   <Host name="10.100.10.63" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
   </Host>
```

Comment: I ran into a completely unrelated problem which has nothing to do with the server.xml. I am getting the following exception regardless of what I put in server.xml java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base
 D:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\Service does not exist or is not a readable directory

I even tried creating a new workspace and creating a new project from scratch but this error just wont get resolved

Comment: Try to boot eclipse with the -clean flag, if it doesn't solve the problem I would start with a fresh eclipse install

Comment: That sounds like the best way to go forward rather than wasting time on finding the cause.